# Cannot capture webcam using dll created by C++ in a C# application

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, dll

I am going to create a C# application to capture webcam using a `dll` created by **C++**. This `dll` allow me to access `OpenCV` library. At the moment, I use *Visual Studio 2013* Expression and `OpenCV 2.49` version. I have already succeeded in capturing Webcam in **C++** program. When I build this into `dll` and read this `dll` from C# code, an error occurred. The error content is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Webcam.exe

Additional Information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

The `dll` code I built in C++ likes this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>

typedef struct _IplImageCs
{
    int width;
    int height;
    int imageSize;
}
IplImageCs;

typedef IplImageCs* pIplImageCs;

extern "C"
{
    _declspec(dllexport) int CaptureFromCamera(int num, pIplImageCs imgCs);
    _declspec(dllexport) void QueryFrame(LPBYTE imageData);
    _declspec(dllexport) void ReleaseCaptureCamera(void);
}

IplImage* img;
CvCapture* capture;
pIplImageCs imgCs;

_declspec(dllexport) int CaptureFromCamera(int num, pIplImageCs imgCs)
{
    //capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(num);
    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(num);
    if (capture == NULL)
        return -1;
    img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    imgCs->width = img->width;
    imgCs->height = img->height;
    imgCs->imageSize = img->imageSize;
    return 0;
}

_declspec(dllexport) void QueryFrame(LPBYTE imageData)
{
    if (capture == NULL)
        return;
    img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    memcpy(imageData, img->imageData, img->imageSize);
}

_declspec(dllexport) void ReleaseCaptureCamera(void)
{
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}
```

In the C#, I wrote this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Webcam
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool bContinue;
        private bool bCompleted;
        private BackgroundWorker bw;
        private Bitmap bmp;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct IplImage
        {
            public int width;
            public int height;
            public int imageSize;
            public IplImage(int init)
            {
                width = init;
                height = init;
                imageSize = init;
            }
        }
        IplImage img;

        [DllImport("Show Camera.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern int CaptureFromCamera(int num, ref IplImage img);
        [DllImport("Show Camera.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern void QueryFrame(Byte[] imageData);
        [DllImport("Show Camera.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern void ReleaseCaptureCamera();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel2.AutoScroll = true;
            bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Processing);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(CompletedProcessing);
            bCompleted = true;
            img = new IplImage(0);
        }

        private void ShowBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CaptureFromCamera(0, ref img);
                //if (CaptureFromCamera(0, ref img) < 0)
                //    return;
                int width = img.width;
                int height = img.height;
                pb.Size = new Size(width, height);
                this.ClientSize = new Size(panel1.Width + panel2.Width, panel2.Height);
                bContinue = true;
                bCompleted = false;
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                ShowBt.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Processing(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (CaptureFromCamera(0, ref img) < 0)
                    return;
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

                Byte[] imageData = new Byte[img.imageSize];

                while (bContinue)
                {
                    QueryFrame(imageData);
                    bmp = new Bitmap(img.width, img.height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
                    Marshal.Copy(imageData, 0, ptr, img.imageSize);
                    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                    pb.Image = bmp;
                    bmp.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }

        private void CompletedProcessing(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            bCompleted = true;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            bContinue = false;
            while (bCompleted != true)
                Application.DoEvents();
        }

        private void QuitBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to correct the code to make it work correcty. Could anyone help me to fix it? Thank you very much for reading my problem and help me. Have a nice weekend, all!

Comment: memcpy(imageData, img->imageData, img->imageSize);// did you ever alloc memory for imageData ? also please do not use IplImages in 2014 anymore. the whole c-api was deprecated long ago.

Comment: I would try to check if the error is caused by the dll or the application. To do that empty out the bodies of the exported dll functions and run the application. If no error occurs the fault is propably caused by the dll code.
Additionally the dll should check all pointers if they are `NULL` before using them (in your code: `imgCs` and `imageData`)